# Dotnet Core DB Scaffold creates additional Collections for Object

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a Mysql Database and want to create a scaffold to try a data-first .net project.  I got the scaffold to work, which was great, but it is creating these false Collections on my model objects for related tables.

For my coin object below, I only have the 5 fields on the top, but it is creating the collections to any of the tables where Coin is a foreign key.  This is not really making any sense to me.  I will never populate this data and cannot see any settings to stop this from happening.

```cs
public partial class Coin
{
    public Coin()
    {
        LedgerTransactions = new HashSet<LedgerTransactions>();
        Price = new HashSet<Price>();
        TradeFeeCoin = new HashSet<Trade>();
        TradeForCoin = new HashSet<Trade>();
        TradeTradeCoin = new HashSet<Trade>();
    }

    [Column(TypeName = "int(11)")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public byte? SortOrd { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "bit(1)")]
    public bool? IsBaseCurrency { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Coin")]
    public ICollection<LedgerTransactions> LedgerTransactions { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Coin")]
    public ICollection<Price> Price { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("FeeCoin")]
    public ICollection<Trade> TradeFeeCoin { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ForCoin")]
    public ICollection<Trade> TradeForCoin { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("TradeCoin")]
    public ICollection<Trade> TradeTradeCoin { get; set; }
}
```

I created this table from a Code-First approach, and that model only had the 5 fields in it that I would expect.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You mean the [navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)? EF will populate these when retrieving data (depending on eager/lazy loading requirements). They are useful.

Comment: I could not get anything to work properly until I removed all the inverse properties.  Kept getting a JSON Serialization issue due to a self referencing loop.  Oh well, removed them and I can at least get it to work.